# Not correct building of Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I have a smal MVC project that can be built in IDEA by Tomcat or webapp-runner in Git. It worked perfectly but suddenly when I build my project it openes in localhost:8080 and saw the problem that my js and css files didn't work. I opened it in debugger (F12) and noticed that there is HTML code of my jsp page, in all of files. If need additional information write in comment I'll send it.

You can see it on this photo:
[image]

Here is structure of my project:

[image]

Additional:

servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ya.pokupay" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!--&lt;!&ndash;Local database&ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"-->
                <!--destroy-method="close">-->
        <!--<beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />-->
        <!--<beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shopDB" />-->
        <!--<beans:property name="username" value="*****" />-->
        <!--<beans:property name="password" value="*****" />-->
    <!--</beans:bean>-->

    <!--Remote database-->
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
                destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/yapokupay" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="******" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="******" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.ya.pokupay.model.Advert</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="advertDAO" class="com.ya.pokupay.dao.AdvertDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="advertService" class="com.ya.pokupay.service.AdvertServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="advertDAO" ref="advertDAO"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ya.pokupay" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

script.js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(".dropdown-menu a").on("click", function () {
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        if (url == '#') {
            history.replaceState('', '', '/');
        } else {
            history.pushState('', '', url);
        }

    })

});
```

Comment: Why your script.js contains HTML code block? Also post your `servlet-context.xml`

Comment: @Lucky , I didn't write it in js. I added my js file in question.

Comment: It's replaced all while building. What it can be? I didn't change anything, and yesterday it worked.

Comment: Can you create a fresh new project so that you can find out if something wrong with your configuration?

Comment: @Lucky I tried to do it. At first it works but when i change smth it crashed and when I remove changes it doesn't work anyway

Comment: Okay can you share the full project code via github or something? I ll try to run it and check

Comment: @Lucky, where I can to send you link?

Comment: In the comments or update your answer. I can get from there. Make sure to remove username, passwords before sharing it.

Comment: It's acting up again today. I rebuilded all project yestarday and it worked, but when I start my PC today and build it I saw HTML code in css and js files in browser.

Comment: How do you (re)build the project? Do you run `mvn clean` and `mvn install` maven goals?

Comment: @Lucky, Just mvn clean and then build through tomcat. Also tried the same things through webapp-runner.

Comment: @Lucky, I tried to reset project by Git to yesterday state and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much to @Lucky for help. I think I found the solve of my question. I wrote in my Controller @RequestMapping("/* *") so you can write anything in url and get the same jsp file. And when app try to get js and css files by path resources/** it got the same jsp page. I just deleted ** and it works.